# Image is not displaying locally

Tags: reactjs

I need set background image to DIV element with props element and if I import the image, it is displayed correctly.

```
import image from '../../../assets/upload/sport/sport1.jpg';

const function = (props) = {
      <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }}> </div>
}
```

But If I use this:

```
const function = (props) = {
      <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(../../../assets/upload/${props.path})`}}> </div>
}
```

props.path contains: sport/sport1.jpg

It is not working. Can you help me, why? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to your image is not correct when you refer to the same file via CSS. Your development environment location is `http://localhost:3000` so having an image that is in a higher up directory is invalid.

When you `import` it, Webpack handles the file and sets the path accordingly.

If you want to refer to a static image outside of Webpack, you can put your image inside the `public` directory, and use:

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: `url(/${props.path})`}}> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand it.